# C++ If statement, repeating from else

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

Just started C++ at university so I've decided to try and do a classic 'shop project' using C++.

I'm just wandering if there is any way to repeat an if statement from the else. For example in the code I'm asking the user if the would like help browsing the shop and if they reply yes then it shows them the options, if they reply no then it continues with the code, however if it isn't yes or no then the code tells the user it can't understand the user.

What I am asking is can I get the user to input the value again and it re-run the if statement without using a loop, or do I have to use a loop?

Here's the bit of code:

```
cin >> help;
if (help == "Yes" || help == "yes")
{
    cout << "These are out current sections that you are able to browse:" << endl;
    cout << "-Offers and Deals (1) \n-Computing (2) \n-Console (3) \n-Audio (4) \n-Electronic Displays (5) \n-Cabling (6) \n-General Accessories (7)" << endl;
}
else if (help == "No" || help == "no")
{
    cout << "You have chosen not to look at our browsing list." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Sorry the system does not understand what you have entered. \n Please use full English (Yes/No)." << endl;

}
```

If anyone could help me with this, that would be great. 
I know its simple code and probably a lot more efficient ways of doing it, just using the ways ive currently been taught at university so far.

Thank in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with using a loop?

Comment: You need to use a loop.

Comment: you can use a `goto` statement if can't use loops.  however, it's more practical to use loops, like the above people said

Comment: As a sidenote, you should be using `std::getline` for accepting strings.

Comment: @Tau: please don't suggest using `goto` to beginners.

Comment: @Ron -- only if the format of the expected strings requires it. Reading single words works just fine with the stream extractor.

Comment: @PeteBecker Indeed. Forgot to mention that. Appreciate it.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo i don't like using `goto` either, but the only other option (except for lopping) is recursion, and that just eats up the stack if enough recursions are called

Comment: @Tau using `goto` is basically having a loop, and abusing `goto` is very poor practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> without using a loop, or do I have to use a loop?

There are ways of achieving this without using a loop, but a loop is exactly the construct that allows you to **repeat** a block of code while a condition is true.

This explicitly expresses your intent and achieves the result you desire.

```
void menu()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int i; std::cin >> i;

             if (i == 0) { action0(); }
        else if (i == 1) { action1(); }
        else if (i == 2) { break; /* Return to caller */ }
        else             { /* Invalid selection, retry */ }
    }
}
```

---

Another reasonable solution uses *recursion*. Example:

```
void menu()
{
    int i; std::cin >> i;

         if (i == 0) { action0(); }
    else if (i == 1) { action1(); }
    else if (i == 2) { return; /* Return to caller */ }
    else             { menu(); /* Invalid selection, retry */ }
}
```

However, this can have several drawbacks compared to a loop. Quoting [François Andrieux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7359094/fran%c3%a7ois-andrieux) from the comments:

> Recursion is a reasonable alternative if loops can't be used, but it's worth mentioning the drawbacks. For example, there may be a limit to the number of times you can recur if tail call optimization doesn't come into play. If it does, then you essentially have a hidden loop. It's also worth mentioning that you can't do this with `main`. It's a mistake many beginners make when they first discover recursion.

Comment: Where you have comments `/* Exit the program */`, the actual effect is to return from the function.    The caller determines what happens when control returns to it.

Comment: I'm not sure if mentioning here recursion is a good idea at all, because the compiler does not necessarily do tail recursion optimization. In that case you might get a stackoverflow after a while.